# Showing layers features data on click in OpenLayers5?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to display layer data on map click but I can't figure out how to do it. There is not an example of this important feature.

I believe it's the `getfeatureinfo` event. [Here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_WMSGetFeatureInfo-WMSGetFeatureInfo.html) is the messy API documentation. Here is what i am trying i am getting `js.js:148 Uncaught ReferenceError: view is not defined`

**Update:**

I am following [this](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html?q=getfeatureinfo) example only and i managed to make it work. 
Though, it's not what I actually want to achieve. I want to access columns as variables and not display the whole table in an iframe as shown in this poor example

[This](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-layers.html) is closer of what i am trying but it loads an xml file. Another weird example.

```js
    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [baseLayer, wmsLayer],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.33386, 35.14710]),
        zoom: 14
      })
    });
       map.on('click', function (evt) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
  var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
  var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857', {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'
    });

  if (url) {
    console.log(url);
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
    // fetch(url).then(function (response) {
    //   return response.text();
    // }).then(function (response) {
    //   // this is the standard way to read the features
    //   var allFeatures = new WMSGetFeatureInfo().readFeatures(response);
    //   console.log(allFeatures.length.toString());
    // });
  }
});
```

Comment: To get a GML response from the server use `'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/vnd.ogc.gml'`  Before calling `new ol.format.WMSGetFeatureInfo().readFeatures(response);`  insert `console.log(response);`  to check the server supports the setting.

Comment: i really got confused. Can you show an example how to properly read features from the layer?

Comment: @Mike Is it possible to receive as response specific columns in JSON but not inside an iframe?

Comment: Yes, but depends on which formats the WMS has been set up to support

Answer (score 3):

You would need to check the GetCapabilities for the WMS to see which formats are supported

[image]

If supported you can parse `application/vnd.ogc.gml` to an OpenLayers feature array using the `WMSGetFeatureInfo` format

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
  var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
  var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857', {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/vnd.ogc.gml'
    });

  if (url) {
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url).then(function (response) {
      return response.text();
    }).then(function (response) {
      // this is the standard way to read the features
      var allFeatures = new WMSGetFeatureInfo().readFeatures(response);
      console.log(allFeatures.length.toString());
    });
  }
});
```

`application/json` returns a GeoJSON

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
  var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
  var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857', {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'
    });

  if (url) {
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url).then(function (response) {
      return response.text();
    }).then(function (response) {
      // this is the standard way to read the features
      var allFeatures = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(response);
      console.log(allFeatures.length.toString());
    });
  }
});
```